# Gulp sourcemaps for scss on single file

Tags: javascript, node.js, sass, gulp, gulp-sourcemaps

```
sass scss/_bootstrap.scss style.css
```

Above code generates properly with sourcemaps but not the below code

```
gulp.task('sass', function () {
    sass('scss/_bootstrap.scss', {sourcemap: true})
        .on('error', function (err) {
            console.error('Error!', err.message);
        })
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(debug())
        .pipe(autoprefixer())
        .pipe(gulpif(mode === 'prod', minifyCss()))
        .pipe(rename("style.css"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dest+'css/'));
});
```

Comment: You getting any error ? Did you required gulp-sourcemap?

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues:

1. You have multiple changes *after* your Sass compilation, but you write the sourcemaps directly after your Sass task. Autoprefixer and MinifyCSS change your output, so the original sourcemaps are not true anymore. Put the `sourcemaps.write()` call to the bottom of your pipe
2. Unfortunately, `gulp-minify-css` sometimes has issues with Sourcemaps. I'd suggest to use the built-in compression process from Sass (even though it's not usually recommended.

This code will work:

```
gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return sass('bower_components/sass-bootstrap/lib/bootstrap.scss', {
            sourcemap: true,
            style: (mod === 'prod' ? 'compressed' : 'nested')
        })
        .on('error', function (err) {
            console.error('Error!', err.message);
        })
        .pipe(debug())
        .pipe(autoprefixer())
        .pipe(rename("style.css"))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('css/'));
});
```